# A difficult calculus question (limits)

Tags: calculus, limits

(transcribed from a pic; couldn't find the source)

If a point $P(x,y)$ lies on the curve $y=f(x)$ such that the following limit exists:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}\frac{\arctan(x)+\arctan(y^{-1})-\arctan(3)}{(x-1)(y-2)} \cdot\arcsin(y-2),
$$then find
$$
10 \lim_{x\to 1/3}\frac{f^{-1}(x)}{3x-1}
$$

I tried solving this question and came up with the following approach:

> Apply L'Hopital's Rule (LHR):
> $$
> =\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{1}{1+1/y^2}\cdot (-y^{-2})dy}{dx}
> $$
> $$
> =\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)} \frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+y^2}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{5}f'(1)
> $$Since this limit exists, $f'(1)\ne \infty$. Now apply LHR to the limit in question:
> $$
> 10\lim_{x\to 1/3} \frac{f^{-1}(x)}{3x-1}
> $$
> $$
> = \frac{10}{3} \lim_{x\to1/3} \frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)}
> $$Since $f(0)=1/3$, this becomes
> $$
> \frac{10}{3} \frac{1}{f'(0)}
> $$Now we can let $f$ be any function, since it's not mentioned in the question. In particular, the linear function interpolating $(0,1/3)$ and $(1,2)$ works, which gives $f'(0)=5/3$. Then the given limit is $2$.

However the answer given is 3. Although I am doubtful of my solution I don’t know what exactly is wrong with it. Also, what would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: I dont know about "the" answer but another function $f(x) = x^2+2x/3 + 1/3$ and $f^{-1}(x) = \frac{-1+\sqrt{9x-2}}{3}$ (for required domain) seems to satisfy all conditions of question, further it gives answer as $5$. I think, given the conditions, many functions can be generated giving different answers for limit.

Comment: @Samjoe in the last bit she's assumed the function to be  a straight line. That's wrong imho.

Comment: @Avnish why is that wrong, it does satisfy question conditions... it is one of the many possible answers

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2826180/lim-x-y-to1-2-left-frac-tan-1x-tan-1-frac1y-tan-13x-1